# start celery worker and enable it for broadcast queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to start celery worker so it only listens to single queue. This is not a problem, I can do this that way:

```
python -m celery worker -A my_module -Q my_queue -c 1
```

But now I also want this `my_queue` queue to be a broadcast queue, so I do this in my celeryconfig:

```
from kombu.common import Broadcast
CELERY_QUEUES = (Broadcast('my_queue'),)
```

But as soon as I do this I cannot start my worker anymore, I get error from rabbitmq:

```
amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: Exchange.declare: (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'my_queue' in vhost 'myvhost': received 'fanout' but current is 'direct'
```

If I start worker without `-Q` (but leaving `Broadcast` in `celeryconfig.py` as described above) and I list rabbitmq queues I can see broadcast queue is created and named like this:

```
bcast.43fecba7-786a-461c-a322-620039b29b8b
```

And similarly if I define this queue within worker (using `-Q` as mentioned above) or as simple `Queue` in `celeryconfig.py` like this:

```
from kombu import Queue
CELERY_QUEUES = (Queue('my_queue'),)
```

I can see this queue in rabbitmq like this:

```
my_queue
```

It apperas it does not matter what I put into `Broadcast` call when defining the queue - this seems to be internal celery name, not passed to rabbitmq.

So I'm guessing when worker is starting then `my_queue` is created and once that's done it cannot be made `Broadcast`.

I can have a worker that listens to any queue (not only to `my_queue`) which I would start by removing the `-Q` argument. But it would be nice to be able to have a single process that only listens to that particular queue since my tasks I throw in there are fast and I'd like to bring latency down as much as possible.

--- Edit 1 ---
Spent some time with this problem and it seems `bcast` queue mentioned above does not appear consistently. After reseting rabbitmq and running celery without `-Q` option `bcast` queue did not appear...

Comment: Suggestion: replace 'my_queue' with a new broadcast queue name, and start your worker processes with '-Q new_broadcast_queue_name', have a try.

Comment: Which celery version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a broker for sending messages, client and workers must agree on same configuration values. If you have to change config, you need to purge existing messages and restart everything so that they are in sync.

When starting a broadcast queue you can set exchange type and configure the queue.

```
from kombu.common import Broadcast
from kombu import Exchange


exchange = Exchange('custom_exchange', type='fanout')

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Broadcast(name='bcast', exchange=exchange),
)
```

Now you can start worker with

```
celery worker -l info -A tasks -Q bcast
```

Comment: Thanks! I have seen some advice about custom_exchange but not in this form.

Comment: Anand, this is related to your answer. I configured fanout queue but it seems workers take the task off the queue but then they are randomly not processing the task. When I inspect active_queues I can see those tasks are listed in the queue and nothing happens with them. Can you help?

Comment: @Greg0ry I am not sure workers are randomly not processing the task. Can you run worker in debug mode(`-l debug`) and see the logs? It might help in understanding why that is happening.

Comment: Thanks Anand, I managed to get this working. My issue was speciffic to what was happening within the broadcast task. On one host I misconfigured my celery service to start two workers processing the broadcast queue and the task logic was failing if two workers requested same resource at the same time. Thanks again!

Comment: I did have some random problems after migrating to celery 4.x so I'll leave a comment here for others who might have the same issue. First thing is that when starting worker you only specify number of processes (i.e. `c:3 1`) without queue number then you will see duplicate tasks when sending them to fanout queue. And second - remember to clear your rabbitmq (i.e. `stop app`, `reset`, `start app` which will erase your rabbitmq status) every time you change your queues since queues created by celery in most cases (depending on config) will be persistent.